# Ext JS Display Field in Combo Box's Tooltip

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I'm trying to create an override to display a tooltip when the user hovers over a combo list item. My override looks like this:

```
Ext.override(Ext.form.ComboBox, {
     tpl: '<tpl for=".">',
             '<div ext:qtip="{Name}" class="x-combo-list-item">{Name}</div>',
           '</tpl>'
});
```

Is there a way I can access the combo box's `displayField` in the `tpl` instead of `{Name}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have looked in a couple of threads before asking this question. I found the answer in the thread **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7658116/combobox-xtemplate-trouble)** (Dumb why I didn't think of doing it this way though). I didn't notice that thread probably because the title was unclear.

This is what I came up with. (Sequence is the way to go, compared to override)

```
Ext.sequence(Ext.form.ComboBox.prototype, 'render', function (combo) {    
    this.tpl = (this.tpl ? this.tpl : '<tpl for="."><div ext:qtip="{' + this.displayField + '}" class="x-combo-list-item">{' + this.displayField + '}</div></tpl>');

    Ext.QuickTips.init();
    Ext.apply(Ext.QuickTips.getQuickTip(), {
        dismissDelay: 0,
        showDelay: 100
    });
});
```

I'll leave this thread open just in case anyone else is looking for this and couldn't find the other thread.

Comment: Thanks for this! I was just able to do something in 2 mins that I assumed would take hours.